# ICAL File Validation (ICAL .NET)

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, .net-core, icalendar

I use [ICAL .NET](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) to create a webcalendar link in my ASP .NET Core application. My service code is inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812921/how-do-i-create-an-internet-calendar-subscription-for-outlook) :

```cs
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("ical/{icalSecret:Guid}")]
        public IActionResult GetICalFeed(Guid icalSecret)
        {

            var calendar = this.eventService.GetUserCalendar(icalSecret);
            var serializer = new CalendarSerializer();
            var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
            var contentType = "text/calendar";
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedCalendar);

            return File(bytes, contentType, "calendar.ics");
        }
```

And the method that generates the calendar :

```cs
        public Calendar GetUserCalendar(Guid icalSecret)
        {
            var user = this._userRepository.GetByICalSecret(icalSecret);
            var events = this._eventRepository.GetUserFutureEvents(user.Id);

             var calendarEvents = events.Select(evt => new CalendarEvent()
             {
                 Start = new CalDateTime(evt.Start),
                 End = new CalDateTime(evt.End),
                 Attendees = evt.Participations.Select(p => new Attendee(){CommonName = p.User.Username, Value = new Uri($"mailto:{p.User.Email}")}).ToList(),
                 Description = evt.Description
             });

             var calendar = new Calendar();
             foreach (var calendarEvent in calendarEvents)
             {
                 calendar.Events.Add(calendarEvent);
             }

             return calendar;
        }
```

And the returned ical fil seems fine to me :

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:STRING
ATTENDEE;CN=test mail:mailto:test@test.fr
ATTENDEE;CN=test droits:mailto:test@test.fr
ATTENDEE;CN=jm:mailto:test@test.com
ATTENDEE;CN=test:mailto:test@test.fr
DESCRIPTION:string
DTEND:20200610T093036
DTSTAMP:20200602T093344Z
DTSTART:20200610T093036
SEQUENCE:0
UID:a8845fea-6d16-49df-aa5e-a8cf61e1575a
END:STRING
END:VCALENDAR
```

But windows calendar app can't open it (says it's damaged) and it fails validation on [this ICAL validator](https://icalendar.org/validator.html).

Do you have any clue of what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok turn out I used the wrong field to store the name of my event in ICAL.NET. One should use the field `Summary` and not the field `Name`.

Comment: ALSO BEGIN:STRING  is not valid, should be BEGIN:VEVENT